# Backend server: how to retain FirebaseApp instance?

Tags: java, firebase, google-admin-sdk, firebase-admin

I've been trying to implement the Firebase `Admin SDK` into our backend server, running on JAVA. The source of my question is this piece of code, provided by Google:

```
FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
    .setDatabaseUrl("https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com/")
    .build();

FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

I've already tested it and have integrated it properly in my code. However, I dislike how it seems like I need to leave the `serviceAccountKey.json` in my server in order to use the Admin SDK.

I have two simple questions for you guys:

1. Is there a way to prevent me from having to store the sensible information (`serviceAccountKey.json`) in the server (since it could possibly be reverse-engineered)?
2. Is the `.setDatabaseUrl(...)` necessary if I'm using my own MySQL DB? The only database Firebase effectively has on their server for me is my user-base, since I use Firebase-authentication. I store the UID in my own DB to refer to users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, there are alternative ways to load the configuration needed for the Admin SDK and it's mentioned in [this post](https://medium.com/google-cloud/firebase-separating-configuration-from-code-in-admin-sdk-d2bcd2e87de6) by Hiranya Jayathilaka:

   You can create a JSON file similar to the one below

   ```
   {  
       "databaseURL": "https://database-name.firebaseio.com",
       "projectId": "my-project-id",
       "storageBucket": "bucket-name.appspot.com"
   }
   ```

   And then create an Environment Variable named `FIREBASE_CONFIG` in your server, and set it to point to the JSON file.

   Then you'd only need to call `FirebaseApp.initializeApp()` with no parameters.
2. As the name suggests, that method is only needed to indicate the Realtime Database URL. If you're not using it, it can be omitted.

Comment: Thank you. Regarding your first answer: I believe I remember reading that 'buckets' are a paid functionality in Firebase. Does this mean I would need to have paid for the services in order to be able to use this method? And sorry that I must ask that, but: what is an Environment Variable? I'm having trouble understanding how I would adapt the piece of code properly.

Comment: Buckets are used on the cloud services from Firebase (like Storage and Firestore). But since you only use Firebase Auth, you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Environment Variable is a variable stored on your server. Since it is part of the environment, it is not exposed the same way the server exposes json files. So it's safer to have your config information there. You might want to look in your server docs or on the internet how to set environment variables. Just perform a quick Google. For example, if you're using Tomcat Server, google: "How to set env variables on Tomcat?"